# Не могу сделать выборку из бд по названию турнира

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица под название tournaments у неё есть два столбца
id и title.

Id/title
1/5x5
2/6x6

Примерно так. Нужно вывести количество строк из таблицы tournaments где title = 5x5.

Как сделать? Все что я писал не работало и выдовало ошибку 1054.

Select * from 'tournaments' where 'title' = 5x5 потом хотел считать через num rows но бд не выводит не одну из строк, где title = 5x5

Comment: 5x5 должно быть строкой - раз.... нормальные кавычки вокруг наименования таблицы и колонки должно быть - два

Comment: приведите тип title в БД - VARCHAR?

Comment: Тип  title VARCHAR(50)

Comment: Сейчас у меня такой запрос SELECT * FROM `tournaments` WHERE `title` = `5x5`

Comment: @Сергей потому что кавычки должны быть *правильные*

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вообще я немного ошибся, я еще попроверял. Ошибку 1054 дает ситуация когда title написан и в столбце и в запросе без кавычек, а 5x5 - в запросе идет без кавычек. А что вы под "правильными" имеете в виду? (я sql неделю назад изучил, пока вопросы не очень глубокие, извините).

Comment: @Сергей в mysql лучше оборачивать наиенования таблиц и колонок в обратные кавычки, строковые значения - в одинарные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Алексей Шиманский уже коротко написал, в чём дело.
Если не очень понятно, что он имел в виду, то вот ниже ваша работающая строка и заполнение тестовой БД.
Посмотрите, в чем у вас разница - где-то должно не хватать кавычек, а где-то лишние они, например.

```
CREATE TABLE tournaments (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR (50) 
);
INSERT INTO tournaments (title)
    VALUES
    ('5x5'),
    ('5x5'),
    ('6x6')
;
SELECT * FROM tournaments;
Select * from tournaments where title = '5x5'
```

Резхультат:

```
Affected rows: 0

Affected rows: 3

Query result:
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 5x5   |
| 2  | 5x5   |
| 3  | 6x6   |
+----+-------+
Affected rows: 3

Query result:
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 5x5   |
| 2  | 5x5   |
+----+-------+
Affected rows: 2
```

Comment: Зачем вы мусорите под каждым ответом этим комметарием?

Comment: Затем, что во многих случаях я вижу "спасибо" или ничего , вместо принятых ответов.  Но учту ваш комментарий и буду удалять из закрытых вопросов (выполнил тут, сейчас пройдусь по старым:-). И, кстати, не под каждым, это для новичков, в основном.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, нашёл ошибку. Отзыв оставит, или как там это называется

Comment: Это называется "принять ответ". Теперь те, кто будет искать по базе знаний (а этот сайт - база знаний), сразу будут видеть, что есть решение у этой проблемы (ну и я +15 баллов получу, первое, впрочем важнее).